# IDA *.idb file structure

Tags: windows, ida

What does the `IDA` `*.idb` file really is? Does it contain only the `disassembler` info or the `program source` also?

Answer (score 0):

`IDB` is a database containing info about the disassembled file. A small description you can find in [IDApro databases description](https://github.com/nlitsme/idbutil/blob/master/IDB-FORMAT.md)

Comment: Ok thx but doesn't contain the disassembled code itself?

Comment: It contains it in an internal binary format.